# Delphi XE - RawByteString vs AnsiString

Tags: delphi, unicode

I had a similar question to this here: [Delphi XE - should I use String or AnsiString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049582/delphi-xe-should-i-use-string-or-ansistring) . After deciding that it is right to use ANSI strings in a (large) library of mine, I have realized that I can actually use RawByteString instead of ANSI. Because I mix UNICODE strings with ANSI strings, my code now has quite few places where it does conversions between them. However, it looks like if I use RawByteString I get rid of those conversions.

Please let me know your opinion about it.
Thanks.

---

Update:
This seems to be disappointing. It looks like the compiler still makes a conversion from RawByteString to string.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var x1, x2: RawByteString;
    s: string;
begin
  x1:= 'a';
  x2:= 'b';
  x1:= x1+ x2;
  s:= x1;              {      <------- Implicit string cast from 'RawByteString' to 'string'     }
end;
```

I think it does some internal workings (such as copying data) and my code will not be much faster and I will still have to add lots of typecasts in my code in order to silence the compiler.

Comment: Any conversion will call the Windows API (e.g.  `System.@UStrFromPCharLen` will call `MultiByteToWideChar` for conversion from `AnsiString` to `UnicodeString`). This will make your code slow. There is even some unwanted conversion in some part of the RTL (see how IntToStr() is [dead slow](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/12/04/SynScaleMM) at least under Delphi 2010).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`RawByteString` is an `AnsiString` with no code page set by default.

When you assign another `string` to this `RawByteString` variable, you'll copy the code page of the source `string`. And this will include a conversion. Sorry.

But there is one another use of `RawByteString`, which is to store plain byte content (e.g. a database BLOB field content, just like an `array of byte`)

To summarize:

- `RawByteString` should be used as a "code page agnostic" parameter to a method or function;
- `RawByteString` can be used as a variable type to store some BLOB data.

If you want to reduce conversion, and would rather use 8 bit char `string` in your application, you should better:

- Do not use the generic `AnsiString` type, which will depend on the current system code page, and by which you'll loose data;
- Rely on UTF-8 encoding, i.e. some 8 bit code page / charset which won't loose any data when converted from or to an `UnicodeString`;
- Don't let the compiler show *warnings* about implicit conversions: all conversion should be made explicit;
- Use your own dedicated set of functions to handle your UTF-8 content.

That exactly what we made for our framework. We wanted to use UTF-8 in its kernel because:

- We rely on UTF-8 encoded JSON for data transmission;
- Memory consumption will be smaller;
- The used *SQLite3* engine will store text as UTF-8 in its database file;
- We wanted a way of handling Unicode text with no loose of data with all versions of Delphi (from Delphi 6 up to XE), and `WideString` was not an option because it's dead slow and you've got the same problem of implicit conversions.

But, in order to achieve best speed, we write some optimized functions to handle our custom string type:

```
  {{ RawUTF8 is an UTF-8 String stored in an AnsiString
    - use this type instead of System.UTF8String, which behavior changed
     between Delphi 2009 compiler and previous versions: our implementation
     is consistent and compatible with all versions of Delphi compiler
    - mimic Delphi 2009 UTF8String, without the charset conversion overhead
    - all conversion to/from AnsiString or RawUnicode must be explicit }
{$ifdef UNICODE} RawUTF8 = type AnsiString(CP_UTF8); // Codepage for an UTF8string
{$else}          RawUTF8 = type AnsiString; {$endif}

/// our fast RawUTF8 version of Trim(), for Unicode only compiler
// - this Trim() is seldom used, but this RawUTF8 specific version is needed
// by Delphi 2009/2010/XE, to avoid two unnecessary conversions into UnicodeString
function Trim(const S: RawUTF8): RawUTF8;

/// our fast RawUTF8 version of Pos(), for Unicode only compiler
// - this Pos() is seldom used, but this RawUTF8 specific version is needed
// by Delphi 2009/2010/XE, to avoid two unnecessary conversions into UnicodeString
function Pos(const substr, str: RawUTF8): Integer; overload; inline;
```

And we reserved the `RawByteString` type for handling BLOB data:

```
{$ifndef UNICODE}
  /// define RawByteString, as it does exist in Delphi 2009/2010/XE
  // - to be used for byte storage into an AnsiString
  // - use this type if you don't want the Delphi compiler not to do any
  // code page conversions when you assign a typed AnsiString to a RawByteString,
  // i.e. a RawUTF8 or a WinAnsiString
  RawByteString = AnsiString;
  /// pointer to a RawByteString
  PRawByteString = ^RawByteString;
{$endif}

/// create a File from a string content
// - uses RawByteString for byte storage, thatever the codepage is
function FileFromString(const Content: RawByteString; const FileName: TFileName;
  FlushOnDisk: boolean=false): boolean;
```

Source code is available [in our repository](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCommons.pas). In this unit, UTF-8 related functions were deeply optimized, with both version in pascal and asm for better speed. We sometimes overloaded default functions (like `Pos`) to avoid conversion, or  More information about how we handled text in the framework is [available here](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=17).

**Last word:**

If you are **sure** that you will only have 7 bit content in your application (no accentuated characters), you may use the default `AnsiString` type in your program. But in this case, you should better add the `AnsiStrings` unit in your `uses` clause to have overloaded string functions which will avoid most unwanted conversion.

Comment: Thanks A. I am absolutely sure that I work only with standard ASCII chars. Actually, I use only a limited portion of the entire ASCII alphabet. The main/only reason for using ANSI strings is memory requirements, since I load large amounts of 'text' in RAM. Unfortunately, MANY important Delphi functions do not have ANSI equivalent or do not accept mixed strings (ansi and unicode) so a lot of implicit/explicit conversion will appear in my code.

Comment: @Altar Take a look at the AnsiStrings units I wrote about at the end of my post. You'll find here most important Delphi functions. In order to be sure to call the correct overloaded function, you could use AnsiString.FunctionName() to avoid any call of the Unicode version. And to be sure, use Alt-F2 and look at the generated code: even if you don't know asm, look at the sub routine called. If its something like `call LStrPos()` this is OK. But if there is some `call UStrFromLStr()` or such before the call of the main function, you'll have a slow conversion. Try to write your own version.

Answer (score 12):

RawByteString is *still* an "AnsiString." It is best described as a "universal receiver" which means it will take on whatever the source-string's codepage is at the point of assignment without forcing a codepage conversion. RawByteString was intended to be used *only* as a function parameter so that you will, as you've discovered, not incur a conversion between AnsiStrings with differing code-page affinities when calling utility functions which take AnsiStrings.

However, in the case above, you're assigning what is essentially an AnsiString to a UnicodeString which **will** incur a conversion. It must do a conversion because the RawByteString has a payload of 8bit-based characters, whereas a string (UnicodeString) has a payload of 16bit-based characters.