# Can we safely use ansiString in mobile with Sydney?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

When I read [Migrating Delphi Code to Mobile from Desktop](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop), they say to avoid using `AnsiString`. Is there any reason for that? `AnsiString` use 2x less memory than `UnicodeString`, and it's a perfect container for JSON. So, can I use `AnsiString` safely, or do I need to stay with `UnicodeString` (and why)?

Comment: Mobile apps use Unicode strings, so you're not saving anything by using AnsiString. They would be converted to Unicode anyway, so you're just wasting processor time by forcing the unnecessary conversions back and forth. You're also wasting memory, as temporary strings have to be allocated during the conversions.

Comment: The Migration docs were written when mobile platforms were first being added to Delphi around XE3. Back then, `AnsiString` was completely disabled on mobile platforms (without a 3rd party compiler patch). In 10.1, `UTF8String` and `RawByteString` were re-enabled. In 10.4, `AnsiString` was re-enabled. So yes, it is "safe" to use `AnsiString` now, but I don't recommend it (even in desktop platforms). And FYI, the best string type for JSON is the native `String` type, or at least `UTF8String`, not `AnsiString`.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't quite understand what you mean by "Mobile apps use Unicode strings". If i receive via an API call a 8 bit string (a json) and I use this json only internaly in my own algorithm why it's will need to be converted in Unicode String ?

Comment: JSON is generally encoded in UTF-8. Using an `AnsiString` to store JSON is a bad idea.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks Remy! I don't agree with you to use UTF8string instead of AnsiString, this because all the 8 bit string functions (pos, stringreplace, uppercase, lowercase, etc.) are declared with AnsiString! and if you exchange an UTF8String with one of those functions it's will be internally converted (8bit UTF8String => UTF16 => 8bit AnsiString)

Comment: @Olivier: UTF8 or AnsiString are the same, they are 8bit string that all what matter. if Tbytes was not badly designed (ie no tiny functions like pos, replace, Tstringlist, etc.) it's will be good to go. UTF8String must absolutely be avoided because it's imply to not use any of those tiny function that are declared with ansiString

Comment: @loki UTF8String uses UTF8 characters which can be from 1 to 4 bytes wide. The english alphabet (json names etc.) uses 8 bits, but the json payload can encode other values in 16,24 or 32 bits. (eg euro symbol) Because the chars are not a constant size functions like Pos aren't implemented.  The position of a character doesn't give you it's address, and accessing a char by index requires scanning the whole string to iodentify where it is - or keeping a lookup. That's why the conversion to UTF16 is made - to get a constant character width.  (Although UTF16 doesn't cover all characters in UTF8).

Comment: @RobLambden I think their is a misunderstanding. UTF8String uses 8bit, yes one character can be encoded in more than one bytes, but at the end it's use 8 bit! and it's up to you to decide how you want to print the representation of those bytes (for example absolutely nothing forbid you to store an JPEG in an utf8 string and decide that the representation of each bytes = the image). this why many time their is misunderstanding, utf8string, ansiString, rawbytestring, etc.. we don't care, it's just 8 BITS, what is important is the interpretation of theses bytes you do!

Comment: I meant exactly what Dalija wrote in the third paragraph of the answer below. Everything that runs on mobile devices uses Unicode, and so doing anything (whether it's in the Delphi RTL code, FMX, or with an external service will use Unicode, which means that there are lots and lots of conversions back and forth that are not necessary if you just do the proper thing and use String instead.

Comment: @loki you are of course correct that you could use the allocated memory of any string type to store any data you want.  Why then would you be interested in Pos, Lowercase, Uppercase, StringReplace etc?  And because JSON is encoded in UTF8 you need to interpret the response as UTF8 - not as a series of 8 bit characters - otherwise when your sting contains a character with more than one byte you will not interpret the data correctly.

Comment: @KenWhite As the question refers to UTF8 it's probably helpful to be explicit about what you mean when you say 'Unicode'.  For most of the Internet Unicode means UTF-8 - MS has spent a lot of time convincing people that Unicode means UTF-16LE which is generally what people means in a Delphi context.  However that's not _really_ unicode it's a specific character encoding.

Comment: @loki "*I don't agree with you to use UTF8string instead of AnsiString*" - The official charset for transporting JSON is UTF-8. "*all the 8 bit string functions ... are declared with AnsiString*" - Embarcadero's fault, they should be updated to take `RawByteString`. "*if you exchange an UTF8String with one of those functions it's will be internally converted*" - a type-cast can avoid that: `Pos('...', PAnsiString(@UTF8)^)`. In any case, working with JSON *in memory* should use `String` only, converting to/from UTF-8 only at boundaries where the JSON enters/leaves the app (files, sockets, etc).

Comment: @RobLambden "*Because the chars are not a constant size functions like Pos aren't implemented*" - that is not why. Those functions have always acted on encoded codeunits, not character codepoints. They could easily work for UTF-8 if Embarcadero had simply updated them to take `RawByteString` instead of `AnsiString`. "*the conversion to UTF16 is made - to get a constant character width*" - UTF-16 is not constant width, due to surrogates. `AnsiString` is not constant width either, when you take MBCS into account.

Comment: @RobLambden "*UTF16 doesn't cover all characters in UTF8*" - yes, it does. In fact, UTF-8 is artificially limited to encode only the Unicode codepoints that UTF-16 supports (the original UTF-8 spec allowed it to use up to 6 bytes to encode codepoints > U+10FFFF, which is the highest codepoint UTF-16 can handle). All UTFs cover the *entire* Unicode repertoire of characters.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - thanks for the correction - I had ignored the 32 character wide surrogates in UTF-16 ...

Comment: @RemyLebeau "In any case, working with JSON in memory should use String" .. this is where we disagree :( you must work in string if you don't care about wasting 2x memory and if you communicate with UI interface or internal api that require 16 bit string, else it's a total non-sense to waste your memory with 16 bit string.

Comment: @loki then we agree to disagree

Comment: @RemyLebeau ahah yes :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use 8-bit strings on mobile platforms. But safety depends on which kind of 8-bit strings you use.

For anything other than Windows, and even on Windows, using `AnsiString` is extremely bad idea. `AnsiString` is legacy type and while it was re-enabled in 10.4 on mobile platforms, that does not mean you should use it, and even less that you can use it safely.

One of the problems with `AnsiString` is that sooner or later in your code it will go through conversion, because default string type used all over RTL and FMX is UTF-16 string type, and you can lose original data.

String types you **can safely use** on mobile (and other platforms) are **`string`, `UTF8String`** and **`RawByteString`.**

When it comes to `RawByteString` it can only be safely used in code-page agnostic operations. See more: [Delphi XE - RawByteString vs AnsiString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061919/delphi-xe-rawbytestring-vs-ansistring)

JSON files don't support ANSI encoding, so Unicode is your only choice. UTF-8 and `UTF8String` will do more than fine, because that is also default encoding for any JSON data exchange.

As far as various `AnsiXXX` functions are concerned, the best option is to write your own routines that will work on UTF-8 strings. You can also use standard functions that work on generic string type, but they are slower because of conversions to UTF-16 and back.

---

**Illustration of data loss when using `AnsiString` on mobile (Android)**

Android specification requires implementation of only few standard character charsets. That includes ISO-8859-1

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset

For anything else you depend on the specific device.

For instance following example with `AnsiString` works fine for French character set, but it fails for Croatian and Chinesse.

```
var
  s: string;
  u: UTF8String;
  a: AnsiString;
begin
  s := 'é à è ù â ê î ô û ç ë ï ü';
  a := s;
  u := s;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(u);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(a);

  s := 'š đ č ć ž Š Đ Č Ć Ž';
  a := s;
  u := s;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(u);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(a);

  s := '新年';
  u := s;
  a := s;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(u);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(a);
end;
```

[image: different character encodings displayed on Android device]

Delphi compiler will issue a warning when you are doing unsafe typecasting between where data loss can occur, and it is prudent to fix all that code, by using some other string type.

```
W1058 Implicit string cast with potential data loss from 'string' to 'AnsiString'
```

There is also a warning when you directly convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 string types, but to clear those warnings you can just explicitly typecast to `string` or `UTF8String` type, since compiler will do appropriate conversion in the background and all information will be retained (Note: Unicode normalization my occur during that process).

```
W1057 Implicit string cast from 'string' to 'UTF8String'
```

Comment: You had me at "JSON files don't support ANSI encoding, so Unicode is your only choice" :-)

Comment: @DaveNottage I suspected that could be quite convincing argument ;)