# Get JSON from URL for Android or Ios

Tags: json, delphi, firemonkey

I have a function to get JSON from URL, and it works properly in Windows when I test it. But after I deploy my project to .apk and install it in my android device, it won't work. It doesn't show any error, so I confused what's wrong.

My code is:

```
function TfrMain.getJSON(url: string): TJSONValue;
var
  HttpClient: TNetHTTPClient;
  strJSON: ansistring;
  HTTPResult: IHTTPResponse;
  objJSON: TJSONObject;
begin
Memo1.Lines.Add('getJSON1');
HttpClient := TNetHTTPClient.Create(self);
Memo1.Lines.Add('getJSON2');
try
  Memo1.Lines.Add(url);
  HTTPResult := HttpClient.Get(url);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('getJSON3');
finally
  HttpClient.Free;
end;
strJSON := '{"data":' + HTTPResult.ContentAsString() + '}';
Memo1.Lines.Add('getJSON4');
Memo1.Lines.Add(strJSON);
objJSON := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(strJSON) as TJSONObject;
Memo1.Lines.Add('getJSON5');
result := objJSON.Get('data').JsonValue as TJSONArray;
Memo1.Lines.Add('getJSON6');
```

I'm using `Memo1.Lines.Add` to trace the error, but it stuck on `Memo1.Lines.Add(url);` in `try` clause and don't execute another code after it. Is HttpClient Object cannot perform for android?

Please give me some clue, thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's `http` as opposed to `https`, you will need to add an attribute the `application` node in AndroidManifest.template.xml, of: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`, otherwise the `Get` call will fail

Comment: Why are you using AnsiString? You shouldn't use AnsiString on Android or iOS, and even less with JSON data See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66690726/4267244

Comment: i agree with Dave Nottage. 
If you want parse json to TFDMemtable you can check this helper function
https://github.com/dondonondon/FMXDesignTemplateAndroid/blob/main/Template%20v3%20(Alexanderia%20%26%20Athens%20-%20V.0.1%20Simple%20Demo)/sources/helpers/BFA.Helper.TFDMemTable.pas